# updating another document based on a where clause in firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I do have this referral thing system and I want to track if the referral code of `user_1` has been used by someone who is registering in the app...

For example this the `user_1` and have it's own personl referral code, I wanna track how many people have used his referral code which is `abc`

```
- users (collection)
  - useruid_user_1(document)
    - totalNumberOfInvites (int 0)
    - personalReferralCode (String "abc")
```

So if I have an registering person and registers the `abc` referral code I wanna increment the `totalNumberOfInvites` to `+1` However I am having a hard time on how to do that.

My plan is to use a where clause wherein I can check if the referralCode used matches the referralCodeInput by the registrant and fetch the user_uid of the referralCode of the owner of the referral code.

Here is my code to it and kinda got stuck onto it.

```
Future<List> countReferralInvites(String referralCodedUsed) async {
  final value = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .where("referralCodeUsed",
          isEqualTo: referralCodedUsed) // <- input referralCode by registrant
      .get();
  if (value.docs.isNotEmpty) {
      // if there is a match on the where clause
      // I wanna fetch the ID of the owner of the referralCode used by the registrant and
      // just simply update the field by incrementing the totalNumberOfInvites field
      // here directly in the if statement.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed my problem.

```
// there are no problem with the code above this if statement


if (value.docs.isNotEmpty) {
   // if the value is not empty. I have created a temporary holder of the 
   // useruid
   var temporaryHolder;
   // I looped the value
   for (var docSnapshot in value.docs) {
      var getUserUid = docSnapshot.get("userUid");
   // and temporaryHolder now holds the useruid.
      temporaryHolder = getUserUid;
    }
   // and here is the function where i needed the useruid..
     ...
  }
```